# Multivariate Linear Regression - Gradient Descent in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am learning machine learning. So I  do some simple practice with the data  I find online. Right now I try to implement linear regression by gradient descent in R. When I run it, I realize that it does not converge and my cost goes high infinitely.  Although I suspect it is somewhere in the part where I calculate gradient, I am not able to find the problem. So lets start presenting my data.

- Dataset : [dataset_multipleRegression.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5klVN2sj_7JLVQ2V1JKWjJhdnM/view?usp=sharing)

My data set contains 4 column : `ROLL ~ UNEM, HGRAD, INC`  So, the goal is finding relationship between `ROLL` and others.

- Let me present my code

  ```
  datavar <- read.csv("dataset.csv")
  attach(datavar)

  X <- cbind(rep(1, 29), UNEM,HGRAD,INC)
  y <- ROLL

  # function where I calculate my prediction
  h <- function(X, theta){
    return(t(theta) %*% X)
  }

  # function where I calculate the cost with current values
  cost <- function(X, y, theta){
    result <- sum((X %*% theta - y)^2 ) / (2*length(y))

    return(result)
  }


  # here I calculate the gradient, 
  #mathematically speaking I calculate derivetive of cost function at given points
  gradient <- function(X, y, theta){
    m <- nrow(X)
    sum <- c(0,0,0,0)

    for (i in 1 : m) {
      sum <- sum + (h(X[i,], theta) - y[i]) * X[i,]
    }
    return(sum)
  }


  # The main algorithm 
  gradientDescent <- function(X, y, maxit){
    alpha <- 0.005
    m <- nrow(X)
    theta <- c(0,0,0,0)

    cost_history <- rep(0,maxit)

    for (i in 1 : maxit) {
      theta <- theta - alpha*(1/m)*gradient(X, y, theta)

      cost_history[i] <- cost(X, y, theta)
    }

    plot(1:maxit, cost_history, type = 'l')

    return(theta)
  }
  ```

I run the code like this

```
 gradientDescent(X, y, 20)
```

This is the output I get :

```
-7.001406e+118  -5.427330e+119  -1.192040e+123  -1.956518e+122
```

So, can you find where  I was wrong. I have already tried different alpha values, didn't make a difference. By the way, I appreciate any tips or good practice from you,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think I finally found the answer. The problem was that I did not appy any feature scaling.  Couse I though it was optional precedure for running the algorithm smoothly. Now it works as expected. You can try to run code with scaled dataset using R's scale() function.